# How to use \tcbhighmath inside a tcolorbox environment properly?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

If I use `\tcbhighmath` outside a `tcolorbox` environment it works normally, but if I use `\tcbhighmath` inside a `tcolorbox` environment it gives an error and doesn't work as expected. Please find the code below. The code generates the image attached. Any idea how to make it work inside the `tcolorbox` environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\tcbset{highlight math style={enhanced,%<-- needed for the `remember' options
colframe=blue,colback=red!10!white,boxsep=0pt}} \begin{align*}
\tcbhighmath[remember as=fx]{f(x)}
             &= \int\limits_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t^2}~dt
              = \left[ -\frac{1}{t} \right]_{1}^{x}\\
             &= -\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{1}\\
&= \tcbhighmath[remember,overlay={%
            \draw[red,very thick,->] (fx.south) to[bend right] ([yshift=2mm]frame.west);}]
          {1-\frac{1}{x}.}
        \end{align*}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Title]

\tcbset{highlight math style={enhanced,%<-- needed for the `remember' options
colframe=red,colback=red!10!white,boxsep=0pt}} \begin{align*}
\tcbhighmath[remember as=fx]{f(x)}
             &= \int\limits_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t^2}~dt
              = \left[ -\frac{1}{t} \right]_{1}^{x}\\
             &= -\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{1}\\
&= \tcbhighmath[remember,overlay={%
            \draw[blue,very thick,->] (fx.south) to[bend right] ([yshift=2mm]frame.west);}]
          {1-\frac{1}{x}.}
        \end{align*}

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: The code works as expected outside the tcolorbox environment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\tcbset{
   highlight math style={
      enhanced,%<-- needed for the `remember' options
      colframe=blue,
      colback=red!10!white,
      boxsep=0pt},
%
   every box on layer 2/.style={ % <---- applied to the nested boxes on layer 2
       highlight math style={
       enhanced,%<-- needed for the `remember' options
       colframe=red,
       colback=red!10!white,
       boxsep=0pt}}} 

\begin{align*}
\tcbhighmath[remember as=fx]{f(x)}
             &= \int\limits_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t^2}~dt
              = \left[ -\frac{1}{t} \right]_{1}^{x}\\
             &= -\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{1}\\
&= \tcbhighmath[remember,overlay={%
            \draw[red,very thick,->] (fx.south) to[bend right] ([yshift=2mm]frame.west);}]
          {1-\frac{1}{x}.}
        \end{align*}
        

\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Title]

 \begin{align*}
\tcbhighmath[remember as=fx]{f(x)}
             &= \int\limits_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t^2}~dt
              = \left[ -\frac{1}{t} \right]_{1}^{x}\\
             &= -\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{1}\\
&= \tcbhighmath[remember,overlay={%
            \draw[blue,very thick,->] (fx.south) to[bend right] ([yshift=2mm]frame.west);}]
          {1-\frac{1}{x}.}
        \end{align*}

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]